# Migrate MySQL to another partition in same server

Tags: mysql, performance, migration

I have a instance of MySQL in a local server. To improve the performance, I put a SSD just for MySQL.

Now I need migrate the MySQL instance, with my databse (a data has 25GB) for the SSD.

What the best way to do that? 
I thinked in export the data and after reinstall the MySQL in SSD and import the data again. But how is a big database, I will have a large downtime.

Are there a another way?

Comment: Stop service. Make a copy of all server data directory to the SSD (for example, all `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0` folder). Edit all paths in my.ini in new location to new values. Edit service command line, specify new my.ini. Edit all another shortcuts (CLI, for example). Start service.

Comment: Is your server Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

For linux (as root user)

1. Stop mysql service through systemctl
2. rsync or cp -a the whole of /var/lib/mysql to your preferred destination.
3. mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql-old
4. edit mysql configuration file and change datadir= under mysqld
5. Start mysql service through systemctl.